# Can an int be aliased as an unsigned int?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, strict-aliasing

Compiler generates code assuming that an `int` can be aliased by an `unsigned int`. The folowing code:

```
int f(int& a, unsigned int& b){
    a=10;
    b=12;
    return a;
}
int f(int& a, double& b){
    a=10;
    b=12;
    return a;
}
```

generates the folowing assembly, using Clang5 (similar code is produced by GCC or ICC):

```
f(int&, unsigned int&): # @f(int&, unsigned int&)
  mov dword ptr [rdi], 10
  mov dword ptr [rsi], 12
  mov eax, dword ptr [rdi]    #return value must be loaded since rdi might equal rsi
  ret
f(int&, double&): # @f(int&, double&)
  mov dword ptr [rdi], 10
  movabs rax, 4622945017495814144
  mov qword ptr [rsi], rax
  mov eax, 10        #return value is a direct value.
  ret
```

In the example above, in the first overload `f` the return value (in `eax` register) is either 10 or 12 if `b` and `a` refer to the same object. In the second overload, `a` and `b` cannot refer to the same object so the return value is always 10.

The strict aliasing rule is expressed by this paragraph of the C++ standard, [[intro.object]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#8):

> [...] Two objects *a* and *b* with overlapping lifetimes that are not bit-fields may have the same address if one is nested within the other, or if at least one is a base class subobject of zero size and they are of different types; otherwise, they have distinct addresses.

So according to this rule, an `int` cannot be aliased by an `unsigned int`.

Questions:

1. Is there an exception to this rule in the C++ standard that would allow aliasing of `int` by `unsigned int`?
2. If not, why all compilers assume this possibility?

Comment: The strict aliasing rule is expressed by N4659 [basic.lval]/8  (point number differs among standard revisions)  , not intro.object . The text you quote has nothing to do with strict aliasing

Comment: @M.M. I thought the strict aliasing rule was derived from this. So the paragraph cited in the anwer lead to exceptions to the rule we could derive from this paragraph. I had overlooked this paragraph.

Comment: intro.object/8 is talking about the case of two objects, not two references that refer to the same object.   The actual standard uses italics for *a* and *b* , not the typeface for code samples `a`, `b`;  those are abstract symbols to indicate that we are talking about *two different objects*, and not two expressions or whatever

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there an exception to this rule in the C++ standard that would allow aliasing of int by unsigned int?

Yes, it's [[basic.lval]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lval#8):

> If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through
>   a glvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is
>   undefined:
>
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object,