# Is casting int32 to uint32 a no-op?

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion, int

I want to stick the bits of an `int32_t` into the type `uint32_t` without any transformation, just a reinterpretation.  The following code does precisely what I want:

```
int32_t  iA = -1;
uint32_t uA = *(uint32_t*)&iA;
```

But I was wondering, can I rely on the following easier to write cast generating the same (or less) assembly, ideally just `mov`s?  (i.e., it'll never do "math" to it, leaving the underlying bits untouched.)

```
int32_t  iB = -1;
uint32_t uB = (uint32_t)iB;

assert(uA == uB); // ?
```

Comment: Your comparison itself is changing them. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233161/compare-int-and-unsigned-int As to whether the cast itself adds any work to what's already being done, probably not, but I don't know.

Comment: @KennyOstrom - oh no, the assert is just there to say I want the first cast to be equal to the second cast (it's comparing two uint)

Comment: You can check the generated assembly yourself on https://gcc.godbolt.org/

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - I have, the second cast generates one fewer instructions (it's roughly the same though), but I wonder if that's just a coincidence of how the compiler does things, or if the standard requires it

Comment: @AnneQuinn The standard doesn't mention assembly at all, it only describes how programs should behave. I got the same results (one instruction less) on GCC, and Clang generated the same assembly for both.

Comment: If you got a different result then you probably compiled without optimizations, which is a meaningless test.

Comment: I would use `memcpy`, that's guaranteed to not change any bits.

Comment: `uint32 uA = *(uint32*)&iA;` Type punning like this is almost always undefined behaviour in C++ – though I’m not completely certain in this case. Anyway, do not even think about doing something like that unless you know for certain and have double checked that it is explicitly allowed by the language or your compiler. On the other hand casting fundamental types is always safe, although I’d suggest a `static_cast`. This isn’t C, after all.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - That's okay, I'm not hung up on the asm itself, I just want to avoid transforming the bits, (for example, if `int32` is instead `float32`, it totally changes the bit pattern before copying, in the second cast, but not the first)

Comment: @besc it is [OK to alias signed/unsigned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48060240/can-an-int-be-aliased-as-an-unsigned-int) types.

Comment: @AnneQuinn It's always a no-op on two's-complement architectures (i.e. on all modern ones). Also C++20 will require two's-complement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Until C++20, the representation of signed integers is implementation-defined. However, `std::intX_t` are [guaranteed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) to have 2s'-complement representation even before C++20:

> `int8_t`, `int16_t`, `int32_t`, `int64_t` - signed integer type with width of exactly 8, 16, 32 and 64 bits respectively with no padding bits and using 2's complement for negative values (provided only if the implementation directly supports the type)

When you write

```
std::int32_t  iA = -1;
std::uint32_t uA = *(std::uint32_t*)&iA;
```

you get the value with all bits set. The standard [says](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#11) that accessing `std::int32_t` through a pointer of type `std::uint32_t*` is permitted if "type is similar to ... a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object". Thus, strictly speaking, we have to ensure that `std::uint32_t` is indeed an unsigned type corresponding to `std::int32_t` before dereferencing the pointer:

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::make_unsigned_t<std::int32_t>, std::uint32_t>);
```

When you write

```
std::int32_t  iB = -1;
std::uint32_t uB = (std::uint32_t)iB;
```

you rely on the conversion into the unsigned type that is [well-defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711522/what-happens-if-i-assign-a-negative-value-to-an-unsigned-variable) and is guaranteed to produce the same value.

As for the assembly, both casts are no-ops:

```
std::uint32_t foo() {
    std::int32_t  iA = -1;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::make_unsigned_t<std::int32_t>, std::uint32_t>);
    return *(std::uint32_t*)&iA;
}

std::uint32_t bar() {
    std::int32_t  iB = -1;
    return (std::uint32_t)iB;
}
```

[result in](https://godbolt.org/z/L4r6hy):

```
foo():
        mov     eax, -1
        ret
bar():
        mov     eax, -1
        ret
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [`memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) is a common solution to avoid undefined behavior when aliasing types.
It was pointed out in the comments that aliasing types which differ only in their signedness is ok, but this would not be the case with `float` and `int` for example.

`memcpy` works as long as the object representation is valid for the type.

Compilers are very good at optimizing `memcpy` calls, in this case [the call is completely optimized away](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/GjFSfn).

Comment: if I could accept multiple answers... I ended up using `memcpy`, static cast for type punning was a bad idea anyway, but I worded the question way too narrowly